# Touch event: when finger is removed from the item

Tags: android, events, touch

I am need to implement functionality when i remove the finger from the item. So i need some event for that.

```
***Scenario:*** 

1. Touch the image view using finger.
2. Remove the finger.
3. Now implement the functionality.
```

**I want the event callback at step 2.**

If some predefined event exist please suggest the name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok. When you touch screen and remove your finger events call :

1. **ACTION_DOWN** - when you first touch
2. **ACTION_MOVE** - when you are moving your finger on screen
3. **ACTION_UP** - when you remove your finger from screen

Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

For that scenario, you can implement [**OnTouchListener**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) for the ImageView.

```
yourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch down");
    } 
    else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      Log.d("TouchTest", "Touch up");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you want to get MotionEvent.ACTION_UP after MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, you should return true on ACTION_DOWN

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestTouchEvents extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
  ImageView imageView;
  Bitmap bitmap;
  Canvas canvas;
  Paint paint;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView);

    Display currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
    float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) dw, (int) dh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
  }

  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      // Do Something
      Log.d("Touch", "Touch down");
      break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

      // Do Something
      Log.d("Touch", "Touch move");
      //imageView.invalidate();

      break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

      // Do Something
      Log.d("Touch", "Touch up");
      //imageView.invalidate();
      break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

      Log.d("Touch", "Touch cancel");
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```